# Images Rerendering inside Styled Component when Chrome Dev Tools is open

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

This is a bit of a strange one and not sure why it's happening exactly.

When the component mounts, I call a function that in my application makes an HTTP request to get an array of Objects. Then I update 3 states within a map method.

`enquiries` - Which is just the response from the HTTP request
`activeProperty` - Which defines which object id is current active
`channelDetails` - parses some of the response data to be used as a prop to pass down to a child component.

```
const [enquiries, setEnquiries] = useState({ loading: true });
const [activeProperty, setActiveProperty] = useState();
const [channelDetails, setChannelDetails] = useState([]);

const getChannels = async () => {
  // In my actual project,this is an http request and I filter responses
  const response = await Enquiries;
  const channelDetailsCopy = [...channelDetails];
  setEnquiries(
    response.map((e, i) => {
      const { property } = e;
      if (property) {
        const { id } = property;
        let tempActiveProperty;
        if (i === 0 && !activeProperty) {
          tempActiveProperty = id;
          setActiveProperty(tempActiveProperty);
        }
      }
      channelDetailsCopy.push(getChannelDetails(e));
      return e;
    })
  );
  setChannelDetails(channelDetailsCopy);
};

useEffect(() => {
  getChannels();
}, []);
```

Then I return a child component `ChannelList` that uses styled components to add styles to the element and renders child elements.

```
const ChannelList = ({ children, listHeight }) => {
  const ChannelListDiv = styled.div`
    height: ${listHeight};
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  `;

  return <ChannelListDiv className={"ChannelList"}>{children}</ChannelListDiv>;
};
```

Inside `ChannelList` component I map over the `enquiries` state and render the `ChannelListItem` component which has an assigned key on the index of the object within the array, and accepts the `channelDetails` state and an `onClick` handler.

```
return (
    <>
      {enquiries &&
      enquiries.length > 0 &&
      !enquiries.loading &&
      channelDetails.length > 0 ? (
        <ChannelList listHeight={"380px"}>
          {enquiries.map((enquiry, i) => {
            return (
              <ChannelListItem
                key={i}
                details={channelDetails[i]}
                activeProperty={activeProperty}
                setActiveProperty={id => setActiveProperty(id)}
              />
            );
          })}
        </ChannelList>
      ) : (
        "loading..."
      )}
    </>
  );
```

In the `ChannelListItem` component I render two images from the `details` prop based on the `channelDetails` state

```
const ChannelListItem = ({ details, setActiveProperty, activeProperty }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    setActiveProperty(details.propId);
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={() => handleClick()} className={`ChannelListItem`}>
      <div className={"ChannelListItemAvatarHeads"}>
        <div
          className={
            "ChannelListItemAvatarHeads-prop ChannelListItemAvatarHead"
          }
          style={{
            backgroundSize: "cover",
            backgroundImage: `url(${details.propertyImage})`
          }}
        />
        <div
          className={
            "ChannelListItemAvatarHeads-agent ChannelListItemAvatarHead"
          }
          style={{
            backgroundSize: "cover",
            backgroundImage: `url(${details.receiverLogo})`
          }}
        />
      </div>
      {activeProperty === details.propId ? <div>active</div> : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now, the issue comes whenever the chrome dev tools window is open and you click on the different `ChannelListItems` the images blink/rerender. I had thought that the diff algorithm would have kicked in here and not rerendered the images as they are the same images?

But it seems that `styled-components` adds a new class every time you click on a `ChannelListItem`, so it rerenders the image. But ONLY when the develop tools window is open?

Why is this? Is there a way around this?

I can use inline styles instead of `styled-components` and it works as expected, though I wanted to see if there was a way around this without removing `styled-components`

I have a [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/embed/image-blinking-9s56c?fontsize=14) to check for yourselves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you re-activate `cache` in devtool on network tab the issue disappear.

So the question becomes why the browser refetch the image when cache is disabled  ;)

It is simply because the dom change so browser re-render it as you mentioned it the class change.

So the class change because the componetn change.
You create a new component at every render.

A simple fix:

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const ChannelListDiv = styled.div`
    height: ${props => props.listHeight};
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
`;


const ChannelList = ({ children, listHeight }) => {
  return <ChannelListDiv listHeight={listHeight} className={"ChannelList"}>{children}</ChannelListDiv>;
};

export default ChannelList;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it has to do with this setting to disable cache (see red marking in image)

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ahh yes! You might be right, this works for me too!

Comment: I guess it rerenders nevertheless, but if cache is not disabled it takes fast enough to be unnoticeable when rerendering.